# Change Woocommerce Product Title h3 to p on Archive Page

Tags: woocommerce

i am looking for a way to change `h3 class="product-title"` on archive page to `<p>`.

Would be great full for help.

Comment: You can change it by making change in files but not recommended for Files you can follow structure like in woocommerce folder template->single-product->title.php there you can see h3 tag and make it to p tag

Answer (score 3):

Unhook the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` function, and replace it with your own function.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'your_custom_function_call', 10 );

function your_custom_function_call() {
     echo '<p class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</p>';
}
```